# Javascript: accessing own Object's variables

Tags: javascript

So the following won't work:

```
var Foo = {
    array1 : ['apples', 'oranges', 'grapes'],
    arrayLength : array1.length // error
}
```

Is there any way I can access `Foo.array1`'s length within the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to do it like this:

```
var Foo = {};
Foo['array1'] = ['apples', 'oranges', 'grapes'];
Foo['arrayLength'] = Foo['array1'].length;
```

Or like this (much cleaner IMHO):

```
var Foo = function() {
   var a = ['apples', 'oranges', 'grapes'];
   return {'array1': a, 'arrayLength':a.length};
}();
```

Another alternative:

```
function Foo(array) {
   this.array1 = array;
   this.arrayLength = array.length;
   //other stuff...
}

var f = new Foo(['apples', 'oranges', 'grapes']);
```

**But really, this doesn't make much sense to me**, *you're already storing the array, why do you need to cache the `length` property?`*

Comment: Your last question made me think why I still needed to cache a property. Thanks Jacob!
I need to learn more about closures ...

Answer (score 0):

or:

```
 var x;
 var Foo = {
     array1 : x = ['apples', 'oranges', 'grapes'],
     arrayLength : x.length
 };
 alert(Foo.arrayLength);
```

clearly not so nice, the Jacob Relkin' solution is better

Comment: If you're going to use a variable, might as well actually *assign it in the same line that you define it.*

Answer (score 0):

You can't really access a property like that.
You can use a function such as :

```
var Foo = {
    array1 : ['apples', 'oranges', 'grapes'],
    arrayLength : function(){ return this.array1.length;}
}
```

which is actually a good thing and I recommend using this since the `Foo.array1` array can change in time, and you probably want the `arrayLength` field to be updated.

Another option would be to use a closure that returns your object literal :

```
var Foo = (function(){
    var array1 = ['apples', 'oranges', 'grapes'];
    return {
        array1 : array1,
        arrayLength : array1.length
    };
})();
```

If you really want to get into oop stuff, you can use "constructors" and `prototypes` for this :

```
var FooClass = function(array){this.init(array);}
FooClass.prototype = new function(){
    this.init = function(array){
        this.array1 = array;
        this.updateArrayLength();
    };
    this.updateArrayLength = function(){
         this.arrayLength =  this.array1.length;
    };
    this.array1 = [];
    this.arrayLength = 0;        
};

var Foo = new FooClass(['apples', 'oranges', 'grapes']),
    Foo2 = new FooClass(['bananas', 'limes', 'grapefruits']);
```

Comment: I happened to have already suggested your second example in my answer.